# make cursor and selection handle above on keyboard in cordova

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova

I'm using cordova android platform

I made a chat room with html css js and there is a problem. 
Html input is bottom of page and when I select text ( I don't know what is name , selection handle or android cursor) show up below of soft keyboard.

I want to know there is any way yo fix that or do something to make that above on the keyboard?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXBra.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EuFg.jpg)

Comment: Please elaborate and add a code example

Comment: there is no special code .just html input